# refreshe metadata on opensea on polygon Network

Tags: polygon, opensea

I see some methods how to refresh collection metadata on opensea.

one method was this

`https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset/[contract-address]/[token-id]/?force_update=true`
but it doesn't work on polygon networks is there any solution for polygon networks?

Answer (score 0):

Polygon and many other networks aren't supported in V1 of the API unfortunately. One solution I was able to find is running a script in the developer console which will refresh individual item's metadata via the browser and Opensea's ui. You can find it on Github:

https://gist.github.com/rcaloras/95bcd4e83cb17ff40d28e8d51fc2e0df

Inlining here for convenience:

```js
// Paste this script into the console on a specfic NFT detail page for your collection.
// e.g. https://opensea.io/assets/ethereum/0x1485297e942ce64e0870ece60179dfda34b4c625/3723
// Adjust i on the for loop for the range of nfts you wish to refresh
// Should work for all chains including Polygon and testnets.

// Returns a Promise that resolves after "ms" Milliseconds
const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))

async function refresh_metadata() { // We need to wrap the loop into an async function for this to work
    for (var i = 1; i <= 1326; i++) {
        await timer(1000); // then the created Promise can be awaited
        var collectionUrl = window.location.href.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/') + '/'
        var nextUrl = collectionUrl + i
        var nextWindow = window.open(nextUrl)
        nextWindow.addEventListener('load', function () {
            // Interact with the dom on this new page
            kabob = nextWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('sc-a143597d-0 sc-f0199734-0 RovoC gdcSkC material-icons')[2]
            kabob.click()
            refresh = nextWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('sc-29427738-0 sc-bdnxRM sc-a8df1259-2 erpyI iPAlIP')[0]
            refresh.click()
            console.log("Refreshed for " + i)
        }, false);
        nextWindow.blur();
        await timer(3000);
        nextWindow.close();
    }
}

refresh_metadata()
```